# Translate Haskell to Prolog - finding sublist of sum

Tags: haskell, prolog, list-comprehension, sublist, prolog-findall

I am trying to translate the following Haskell code:

```
-- sublistSums list sum returns a list of the sublists of list that add up to sum
sublistSums :: [Int] -> Int -> [[Int]]
sublistSums [] 0 = [[]]
sublistSums [] _ = []
sublistSums (x:xs) sum = [x:tailList | tailList <- sublistSums xs (sum-x)] ++
                         sublistSums xs sum
```

...into Prolog. The code is supposed to give me a list of all the lists whose sum adds up to a target number.  For example,

```
?- sublistSums([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],6).
```

Should give you `[[1,2,3]]` if it binds because `1+2+3=6.`

This is what I have so far:

```
sublistSums([], 0) :-
    sublistSums([],0,[]).
sublistSums([], _) :-
    sublistSums([],0,[]).
sublistSums([x|xs], sum) :-
    conc(conc(x,findall(xs,(sublistSums(xs, (sum-x))),List)), sublistSums(xs, sum)).
```

When I call the sublistSums function, however, it gives me this:

```
?- sublistSums([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],6).
false.
```

I also tried:

```
sublistSums([], 0, ReList) :-
   [[]].
sublistSums([], _, ReList) :-
   [].
sublistSums([x|xs], sum, ReList) :-
   conc(conc(x,findall(xs,(sublistSums(xs, (sum-x)),ReList),List)), sublistSums(xs, sum, ReList)).
```

Still gives me the same results.  Not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few elementary issues in your Prolog code:

- `sum` is a Prolog **atom**, so it will *never* unify with a list.
- in Prolog, we define **relations** between entities, and you need predicate *arguments* to refer to these entities.

Therefore, you cannot translate the code *verbatim*. Still, a *quite* literal Haskell→Prolog translation is possible, if you for example introduce a new *argument* to hold the original function's return value. Your second snippet goes into this direction, but it is not self-contained, and also contains several mistakes. For example `xs` and `sum` are **atoms**, whereas Prolog **variables** start with an uppercase letter or with an underscore.

In addition, if you continue to attempt a *literal* translation, you will forego the chance to *truly* benefit from the generality of **relations**. Typical Prolog predicates can be used not only in *one*, but in *several* directions, and you can use them not only to *compute*, but also to *test* and to *complete* partial results.

---

Thus, instead of a literal translation, I would like to show you a more **idiomatic** Prolog solution of this task.

Our first observation, which is clear from the **type signature**: We are reasoning over **integers**. Thus, I recommend you use your Prolog system's **CLP(FD) constraints** for fully *declarative* integer arithmetic. See [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for more information about this feature.

Second, the task can be seen as "filtering" a list, and for this we use `tfilter/3` which is provided by [**library(reif)**](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl).

Here is the complete Prolog solution:

```
sublist_sum(Lss0, Sum, Lss) :-
        tfilter(sum_intlist(Sum), Lss0, Lss).

sum_intlist(Sum, Ls, T)  :-
        sum(Ls, #=, Sum0),
        zcompare(C, Sum0, Sum),
        eq_truth(C, T).

eq_truth(=, true).
eq_truth(<, false).
eq_truth(>, false).
```

Think of this predicate as *relating* a list `Lss0`, a *sum*, and a second list `Lss`, such that all requirements you state are satisfied. Note that I do not say which of these arguments are "given", because any of them may be fully, partially, or not at all specified.

Your example works as required:

```
?- sublist_sum([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], 6, Ls).
Ls = [[1, 2, 3]].
```

This example stays within the confines of the original *function*: The first and second arguments are fully specified, and the third one is used to represent the "result".

However, as is typical for Prolog, we can also more **general** queries, in which not only the "result", but also other parts are left unspecified. Clearly, this is well beyond the scope of functions, and a literal translation of the original code may not have this benefit.

For example:

```
?- sublist_sum([[1,2,N]], 6, Ls).
```

In this case, we have left `N` **unspecified**, and ask Prolog to consider *all* cases that may apply for `N`.

In response, Prolog *generates* the different possibilities, presented as a **disjunction**:

```
N = 3,
Ls = [[1, 2, 3]] ;
Ls = [],
N in inf..2,
-3+_10694#=N,
_10694 in inf..5 ;
Ls = [],
N in 4..sup,
-3+_10662#=N,
_10662 in 7..sup.
```

Note how `Ls` depends on `N`.

We can also generalize this *further*, and leave even the **sum** unspecified:

```
?- sublist_sum([[A,B,C]], Sum, Ls).
Ls = [[A, B, C]],
A+B+C#=Sum ;
Ls = [],
A+B+C#=_15806,
_15806#=<Sum+ -1,
zcompare(<, _15806, Sum) ;
Ls = [],
A+B+C#=_15806,
Sum#=<_15806+ -1,
zcompare(>, _15806, Sum).
```

Again, Prolog enumerates the different cases.

Moreover, we can **specialize** the query and use it to **test** the relation:

```
?- sublist_sum([[1,2,3]], 5, []).
true.
```

Here, we have asked: *Does this **concrete case** hold?*, and Prolog responds with `true`, indicating that the relation works exactly as intended in this case.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, is there a way to solve the problem without usage of library(reif)?

Comment: If you want to destroy the declarative meaning of your code, the widely used predicate `include/3` is a good way to do it, since it impurely commits to only one of the branches even if both may still apply. You can easily find an implementation and also implement it yourself. The resulting code will likely be as limited as the Haskell version.

Comment: Okay, understood. Also, I don't understand why sum_intlist(Sum) is called with one variable but three are expected for sum_intlist(Sum, Ls, T)? I tried running it and it gives me an error because of that. Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: This is a *closure*, or, as you would say in Haskell, *partially applied*. The predicate `tfilter/3` always calls the closure with two *additional* arguments: The list element, and the truth value, in order to decide whether that element must be included or not. Of course, *both* options may be applicable, and in such cases both answers are generated on backtracking. `tfilter/3` automatically commits to one of the branches *when it is safe to do so*, i.e., when no other branch can apply because the argument is already sufficiently instantiated.

Comment: `sum_intlist` rather `sum_intlist_t`?

Comment: SWI variable names like `_15806`  are a pain. Worse, they appear most often in the more general answers.... Some nice SO answers could be even nicer, with nicely laid out compact disjunctions. Sad!